# PHP / VB.NET POST Request

Tags: php, vb.net

I am trying to connect to an API that is provided by our telecomms provider, all they have provided me with is a PHP webpage that want me to host.

I have in-turn tried to convert this into VB .NET which makes a lot more sense to me and would be easier to insert the data that is being collected into SQL etc.

I'm struggling to get the API to even respond to the basic 'AUTH' that it has.

```
<?php
// IPscape API auth details
define(IPS_API_KEY, "KEY");
define(IPS_API_USERPWD, "USER:PASSWORD");

// API URLs
define(IPS_AUTH_SERVICE, "URL");
define(IPS_CAMPAIGN_SERVICE, "URL");

define(VERBOSE, true);
define(DEBUG, false);

// IPscape API auth
if (VERBOSE || DEBUG) { echo "IPscape API auth starting\n"; }
$ips_auth_response = ips_api_auth();
if (VERBOSE || DEBUG) { echo "IPscape API auth complete\n"; if (DEBUG) { echo print_r($ips_auth_response."\n",true); }}
```

Now my PHP is extremely sketchy but I'm pretty sure the auth is calling the following function:

```
function ips_api_auth() {

    $api_key = "apikey=".IPS_API_KEY;

    $ips_auth = curl_init(IPS_AUTH_SERVICE);
    curl_setopt($ips_auth, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ips_auth, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_key);
    curl_setopt($ips_auth, CURLOPT_USERPWD, IPS_API_USERPWD);
    curl_setopt($ips_auth, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $ips_auth_response = curl_exec($ips_auth);

    curl_close($ips_auth);
    return $ips_auth_response;
}
?>
```

I have essentially typed this up as the following:

```
Public IPS_API_KEY As String = "KEY"
    Public IPS_API_USERPWD As String = "USER:PASSWORD"

    Public IPS_AUTH_SERVICE As String = "URL"
    Public IPS_CAMPAIGN_SERVICE As String = "URL"
    Sub Main()

        Dim authresponse As String

        authresponse = ips_api_auth()

    End Sub

    Public Function ips_api_auth As String

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        Dim myReq as HttpWebRequest
        Dim myResp as HttpWebResponse

        myReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(IPS_AUTH_SERVICE)

        myreq.Method = "POST"
        myReq.contenttype = "application/json"
        myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization","Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IPS_API_USERPWD)))


        Dim myData As String = "apikey=" & IPS_API_KEY
        myReq.GetRequestStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData).Count)
        myResp = myReq.GetResponse
        Dim myreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
        Dim myText As String
        myText = myreader.ReadToEnd

    End Function
```

How whatever which way I try this I'm getting

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'
```

Now I'm pretty sure I've covered everything and I have been staring at it long enough that I could do with another set of eyes.

Any thoughts from people a bit more well-versed in PHP than myself.

Cheers